# Should I be using interfaces here?

Tags: php, class

I have a class called DataType, and then I have another class which extends DataType and can be saved to a database:

```
class PersistableDataType extends DataType
```

Then I have more classes that extend PersistableDataType. PersistableDataType itself is never instantiated. I have read that this kind of situation is where one should consider using interfaces.

If I made a Persistable interface, though, then wouldn't I have to implement the save functionality in every single class? The way I currently have things, I only have to implement saving functionality in PersistableDataType, and then every sub-class inherits that functionality.

What is the "correct" way to approach this?

Comment: The datatype sounds very generic. You could have a persistable interface, a Abstract PersistentDataType which implement the interface Persistable. Then each child overwrite whatever behavior deviates from the base. At the same time you could type hint with the interface instead of making a concrete/type dependency, making it easy to exchange dependencies. You can pass other classes outside the object class that adhere to the functionality. Make sure to try think about SOLID principles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a normal class or an abstraction depends on the purpose of your `PersistableDataType` class - primarily: does it make sense to have an actual instance of that class? If the answer is yes, then create it as a normal class and extend it. If it doesn't make sense and the methods it contains are purely for use by inheriting classes, create it as a class abstraction. *Both* ways allow your class to contain method declarations that pass on content (so no, you wont have to rewrite the same save function in all inheriting classes), and any non-abstract methods can still be overwritten by inheriting classes - only abstract methods must use the same signature and visibility.

So ultimately the "correct" approach depends not on whether you actually create an instance of your class, but on whether it makes sense to have an instance of your class. Yes: normal class; no: abstract class.